# Issue with the Liquid Maps in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I am trying to convert a JSON from one schema to another and I am having issue in transforming the decimal data types. Whenever the decimals are transformed, it is getting rounded off up to 5 decimal places. Below mentioned is the input:

```
{
  "inputvalue": 44.84839234
}
```

The output is coming as:

```
{
  "outputvalue": 44.84839
}
```

The Liquid map is as below:

```
{   
    "outputvalue": {{content.inputvalue}}
}
```

Why is this rounding off happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Microsoft, this is a bug and will be fixed soon. See the post below:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50905#issuecomment-606404515

Answer (score 0):

According to some test, it should be a problem caused by design. In my test, I use the filter "[round](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/round/)" to keep more than five decimal places. But it still show as `44.84839`. So I think liquid template in azure can not implement this requirement, the only workaround which we can do is convert the `inputvalue` from number to string when you generate the data source.

By the way, if we use `{% assign a = content.inputvalue | Times: 1 %}`, we can keep more decimals. But the number will be imprecise(maybe because of version), you can also have a try and see if it can meet your needs.

Comment: Times will not work as the number was getting changed. Yes, I know that converting to string get it worked.